# how to make this loop functional after the first run?

Tags: c++, while-loop

This is my code, but after the first try, no matter the given number, it only says `"number is not perfect"`, and bypass the "for" loop.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, i, x = 1, s = 1;
  char z;

  while (x) {
    cout << "please enter a number for incpection : ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if ((n % i) == 0)
        s += (n / i);
    }

    if (s == n) {
      cout << "the entered number is complete\n";
    } else {
      cout << "number is not perfect\n";
    }

    cout << "do you wish to continue ?(y/n) : ";
    cin >> z;

    if (z == 'y')
      continue;
    else
      x = 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I tried checking the Syntax and "{" repositioning but didn't work

Comment: You add to s in the loop `s +=(n/i);`, but never reset s again. So it is just growing, and growing.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. Really important trick (I know it sounds silly): Use your IDE/Code editor to automatically indent your code consistently, keep line breaks consistent. This **really** (I promise) helps us to read your code, and also, it **really** helps you find your own structural mistakes in your code (I also promise; I made tons of such).

Comment: I did that for you here! (how much clearer it now becomes for me to see when `s` is incremented!) Also, the material you're learning C++ from seems to think C++ is like C from 1989; you do not need (nor should you) declare all variables at the start of a function body. That's actually one of the main reasons people write C++ instead of C: Variables have life times that can be finely granular. Also, C++ has `bool`, you don't use `int` for truth values. You really might want to find better learning material :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem really lies in the fact that for some reason, you introduce and set all the variables only at the beginning of the function; that can't work, because you need to "reset" `s` after every number. A version of your code that introduces the variables where they are actually "living" solves that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool x = true;
  while (x) {
    int n;
    cout << "please enter a number for incpection : ";
    cin >> n;

    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if ((n % i) == 0)
        s += (n / i);
    }
    if (s == n) {
      cout << "the entered number is complete\n";
    } else {
      cout << "number is not perfect\n";
    }
    cout << "do you wish to continue ?(y/n) : ";
    
    char z;
    cin >> z;
    if (z != 'y')
      x = false;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Because we do want you to learn to code successfully, I'll also point out that your variable names are *very bad*, and that makes it hard, already at your small program size, to reason (as a human) about what they do. Variable names don't "cost" anything, so use them to describe what you're doing. 100% same code as above, but much clearer to me, if I need to read this same code tomorrow morning:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    int test_number;
    cout << "please enter a number for incpection : ";
    cin >> test_number;

    int sum_of_divisors = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < test_number; i++) {
      if ((test_number % i) == 0)
        sum_of_divisors += (test_number / i);
    }
    if (sum_of_divisors == test_number) {
      cout << "the entered number is complete\n";
    } else {
      cout << "number is not perfect\n";
    }

    char answer;
    cout << "do you wish to continue ?(y/n) : ";
    cin >> answer;
    done = (answer != 'y');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, the way you declared your variables at the start of the function body prevents `s` for restarting to `1` after the first run.

You should declare your variables "as late as possible". Something like that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x = 1;

  while (x) {
    cout << "please enter a number for incpection : ";

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int s = 1; // fresh new s value for each loop iteration

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if ((n % i) == 0)
        s += (n / i);
    }

    if (s == n) {
      cout << "the entered number is complete\n";
    } else {
      cout << "number is not perfect\n";
    }

    cout << "do you wish to continue ?(y/n) : ";

    char z;
    cin >> z;

    /*if (z == 'y') {
      continue;
    } else {
      x = 0;
    }*/
    if (z == 'n') { // simpler version
      x = 0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```